# "Apt-get update" error

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

I am new for Linux.I am using Debian Jessie version for Lichee Pi Zero. The image file for this Debian version was created specifically for the Lichee Pi development board and is provided by the manufacturer. And I am using this. When I tried the update with `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` the update takes a lot of time and "Reading package lists %x" appears on the command screen.It takes about 1 hour for this percentage to reach 24. That's why I can't finish the update either.

What is the problem?

I tried multiple times and none of them finished in 1 hour so I canceled the updates.

If i need Debian update;
Does updating the Debian version mean rebuilding the image file? Or can I do this update using commands in Jessie?

Answer (score 0):

You're 2½ years behind the times: there is [no Jessie](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/) anymore. Even Jessie's successor [Stretch](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/) hit end of life six months ago.

At this point your best option is to reinstall with the [current release](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/) of Debian. Or contact the board manufacturer since it is they that provided the Jessie release for you.

Comment: As pointed out, the Debian version you have is very old, if that's what you can get for that board you should seek information on using it with some people that have knowledge about that board. If you can get a newer version of Debian for that board, you should try that.

Comment: Beside, having opened the Debian image I found at https://licheepizero.us/downloads/lichee_zero_test_Debian_LXDE.tar.bz2 the Debian (jessie) source that is configured uses `deb [arch=armhf] http://ftp.cn.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free` . It's possible this specific mirror is not always adequate. But then I even wonder how it could work in the end without an option to ignore the expired date on the release file.